# PHPSESSID set SameSite=NONE

Tags: magento2, php, session, payment-gateway, cookie

PHPSESSID cookie is set to default sameSite= lax, how to change it to sameSite=none?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Pleas use this free extension https://github.com/Veriteworks/CookieFix it will help you to fix your problem